# Comparing integer to a range

Tags: c++, integer

Is there a simple way to see if an integer falls in a range?

like

```
int x = 15;
if(x==1x)
{
std::cout << "Yes it falls in the range 10-19" << std::endl;
}
```

As far as I understand, the closest thing to that is

```
((x>9) && (x<20))?(std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl):(std::cout << "No" << std::endl);
```

Or something like that.

Is there something like the first way?

Comment: you could like a *not* simple way, like defining your range class with == overloaded...

Comment: Here's two stupid options that would work for your case: 1) Convert it to a string, check that its length is 2 and the first character is '1'  2) `if(x/10 == 1)` -- But don't do either of those two things, because you will just confuse your readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no other way than the second version you have.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for an inclusive range the I'd use `>=` and `<=` as (in my opinion) it reads better for a range check. However, there's no clever way in C++ to check for a range other than a conditional using `if` or `?:` and and `&&` expression.